# Monitor which content assists are used in Eclipse RCP

Tags: eclipse

I have an Eclipse RCP (an IDE for the VHDL language), which has several content assists for generating skeleton code. I would like to track which content assist is actually used.

I notice that my classes content proposal code gets called when the user presses CTRL+space. This is when the user sees the content proposals that they can choose from. I would like to track which content proposal is actually selected and used. I've looked at the Eclipse source code and googled, but I cannot find an easy way to get a notification when a given content proposal is used.

How can I be notified (and track) which content assist / content proposal / autocomplete is actually used in an Eclipse environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the completion proposals are in your code you could use a subclass of `CompletionProposal` and override the `apply` method to record the proposal.

```java
@Override
public void apply(IDocument document)
{
  super.apply(document);

  // TODO add your code to record the apply
}
```